# I'm doing a user study on PlanetMath - is there an appropriate way to solicit participation here

Tags: discussion, support

Hello: I'm on the board of directors of the nonprofit [PlanetMath.org](http://planetmath.org), and I'm doing my Ph. D. at the UK's Open University on the topic of "Peer Supported Problem Solving and Mathematical Knowledge".  We've built a lot of new features into PlanetMath and I'd be interested to see how people who are used to the features of math.stackexchange.com feel about them.

I don't want to spam your site though, so I'm asking here if there as a way to appropriate way to advertise my need for study participants without being spammy.

For the record: I only need 3 people to form a small focus group, and I have $50 USD, or £36 GBP vouchers to offer.  Other details on the study are [here](http://planetmath.org/node/87399).

Note that this message itself is not intended to be "spam" -- the details are just here for you to evaluate my request.  My own hypothesis is that maybe I should post about this in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics).  Other ideas?

Comment: I also thought "chat" when I saw the request.

Comment: Can I partcipate?

Comment: @gekkostate - sure! Actually one other person emailed me so I'm really only looking for one more.  Can you send me a note at holtzermann17¡gmail.com (if you create and include a PlanetMath username that would be ideal).

Comment: @JoeCorneli I have sent the e-mail to holtzermann17 @ gmail.com

Comment: is the members already complete?

Answer (score 6):

Go ahead and post an ad to the [Community Promotion Ads - 2013](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6774/community-promotion-ads-2013) thread. Considering that your question here got 12 up votes, I'm sure it will be "vetted" for display on the main site soon.

Comment: If there are only three places on the focus group, I don't think that an ad is a great idea.

Comment: @Asaf: oops! I didn't pay too much attention to the 3rd paragraph... sorry about that.

Comment: I was up all night, what's your excuse? ;-)

Comment: None whatsoever. After my vacation last week, I ought to be refreshed, one should think.

Comment: Nonsense! After a vacation one should suffer from a general malaise, due to the end of loafing around and getting back to work!

Comment: @WillieWong - Thanks - maybe we'll add a promo of PlanetMath itself there - but I think that's not the right way to recruit participants for this small study.  Cheers!

Comment: @WillieWong - actually it looks like PM is already in the listing :-)

Answer (score 6):

Tentative answer: it looks like posting here in Meta.Math.SXE was the best way to achieve my aim.